# How to pass a vector (or similar) into a variadic template

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

Suppose I have the following code:

```
template <typename... Args>
void DoSomething(const Args&... args)
{
    for (const auto& arg : {args...})
    {
        // Does something
    }
}
```

Now let's say I'm calling this from another function, and want to pass in an `std::vector` (or somehow modify the vector in such a way that it could be used with this)

```
void DoSomethingElse()
{
    // This is how I'd use the function normally
    DoSomething(50, 60, 25);

    // But this is something I'd like to be able to do as well
    std::vector<int> vec{50, 60, 25};
    DoSomething(??); // <- Ideally I'd pass in "vec" somehow
}
```

Is there anyway to do this? I've also considered using `std::initializer_list` instead of variadic templates, but the issue still remains that I have no way to passing in existing data.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want `DoSomething()` to modify the passed vector? Your template parameter pack (`Args`) is `const`-qualified.

Comment: @水飲み鳥 Nope. In the actual code I'm writing (didn't feel it was necessary to post the whole thing for one example), it reads the contents and adds a modified version _of_ the contents to another vector inside the class. Hopefully that made sense.

Comment: You could accept two iterators. Variadic templates is a compile time feature.

Comment: Write two methods: the `std::initializer_list` one then just passes a pair of iterators to the other one.  Or are you unable to modify `DoSomething()`?

Comment: Would the syntax `DoSomething({50, 60, 25});` be ok?

Comment: `std::vector` is impossible. Since it's length can't be determined at compile time. Unless you write an overloading for it.

Comment: @水飲み鳥 Yeah, that would be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one approach that uses SFINAE.
Pass one element and it will be assumed it's something that works in a `ranged for-loop`.

If you pass several arguments it constructs a vector and iterates over that.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

template <typename... Args, typename std::enable_if<(sizeof...(Args) > 1), int>::type = 0>
void DoSomething(const Args&... args)
{
    for (auto& a : {typename std::common_type<Args...>::type(args)...})
    {
        cout << a << endl;
    }
}

template <typename Arg>
void DoSomething(Arg& arg)
{
    for (auto a : arg)
    {
        std::cout << a << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    DoSomething(10, 50, 74);

    std::vector<int> foo = {12,15,19};
    DoSomething(foo);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In your first overloading, `std::vector` is unnecessary and will cause additional memory allocation. Use `for (auto& a : {static_cast<std::common_type_t<Args...>const &>(args)...}) { /*...*/ }`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the syntax `DoSomething({50, 60, 25})` is acceptable, you could first write a non-variadic function template for containers:

```
template <typename T>
void DoSomething(const T& coll) 
{
    for (const auto& arg : coll) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Then, a non-variadic function template for `std::initializer_list<>`:

```
template<typename T>
void DoSomething(const std::initializer_list<T>& lst)
{
    for (const auto& elem: lst) {
       // ...
    }
}
```

They can be used this way:

```
void DoSomethingElse()
{
    std::vector<int> vec{50, 60, 25};
    std::list<int> lst{50, 60, 25};

    // 1st function template
    DoSomething(vec);
    DoSomething(lst);

    // 2nd function template
    DoSomething({50, 60, 25});
}
```

---

In order to avoid code duplication, the second function template could create a `std::vector` from the `std::initializer_list` argument and then call the other function template with that vector:

```
template<typename T>
void DoSomething(const std::initializer_list<T>& lst)
{
    std::vector<T> vec(lst);
    DoSomething(vec);
}
```